# How to show word diffs in Magit?

Tags: magit, words

Some people put one sentence or even one paragraph on one line.  When someone fixes a spelling error in such a line it is difficult to spot the change in Magit log.  How can I toggle Magit log to show me the differences at the word rather than the whole-line level?

Edit1: When I press `D t` or `magit-diff-refine-hunk` in the Magit log buffer I see no difference.  I.e., single word changes are still shown as very long red/green lines.

Edit2: The main developer of Magit does not want to add this feature.  See [here](https://github.com/magit/magit/issues/1615) for his motivation.  (This question cannot be a duplicate of another solved issue, because the current issue apparently cannot be solved within the current version of Magit.)

Comment: See https://github.com/magit/magit/issues/1615

Comment: @npostavs The issue you link to is about Magit diff mode.  When I press 'D t' in a Magit log buffer -- the answer to the Magit diff issue -- I see no change (still one very long line, while only one word was changed).  PS: I did not find the issue you link to, probably because it's title is completely ungrammatical/unintelligible.

Comment: @xuhdev Thanks for the related Github issue!  The discussion over there is a bit over my head to be honest...

Comment: @WouterBeek You can simply read the very final comment...

Comment: @xuhdev IIUC then the main developer of Magit does not want to implement this feature because that results in non-actionable hunks.  That makes a lot of sense for Magit diff buffers but not for Magit log buffers (when being actionable is less of an issue).

Comment: Do you think it worth a bug report?

Comment: `D t` works the same in both diff and revision buffers. I agree the question I linked has a bad title, which is why it's useful to have your question point to it.

Comment: Actually, by "in the log", you mean in a *revision* buffer, right?

Comment: @npostavs Yes, the buffer is called `*magit-revision: ...`